# Should I use UserDefaults or Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I want to store how many days in a row the user has met their daily goal as an integer, and the date they first started this 'streak' of days.

I don't know whether Core Data seems a bit much for this simple functionality, however, I don't want a user to potentially lose their 'streak'.

Is User Defaults safe enough for this use case? Should I use UserDefaults or Core Data?

Answer (score 1):

You only require to store just two `variables` which can be combined into a single `struct` and stored as a single key/value pair in the `UserDefaults`. `CoreData` seems to be an over-kill for your situation. `CoreData` is usually used to store large amounts of data. Say you had to store an array of information regarding each day, then you should definitely go for `CoreData`. And FYI: Data stored in `UserDefaults` are persisted just like the data stored in `CoreData`, so you don't have to worry about losing the data stored in `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

UserDefaults won't be cleared or removed unless the app is deleted (even app updates and backups are fine), so you're safe to persist data there which isn't considered sensitive.

In my opinion, UserDefaults seems to fit your situation the best!